# Android default onCreateOptionsMenu adding settings tab that I can't locate

Tags: android, android-actionbar, settings

When testing the app, and pressing the menu button on my Android 2.2 phone, it gives me a settings bar, when clicked, takes me nowhere. However, when I see the code that sets it up in my main.class file, it isn't found.

In my strings file, it was created by itself and called itself " action_settings ". I tried deleting the line, but it made the app unable to compile. What do I do here?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // three lines below are default
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    // return true;

    // Make MenuInflater
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
    //MENU//

    menu.add(1, 1, Menu.FIRST, "Settings MENU?");
    menu.add(1, 2, Menu.FIRST +1, "Clear");
    menu.add(1, 3, Menu.FIRST +2, "Feedback");
    menu.add(1, 4, Menu.FIRST +3, "About");


    // Return True
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your res/menu/main.xml that is being inflated?

Comment: I see whats wrong here. I copy/pasted code that I didnt understand. Menu/main has an item in it called action_settings...

Comment: I just don't know what inflater is nor what its used for.

Comment: A `MenuInflater` inflates a menu from XML, adding each element into the `Menu` that is passed to `inflate`. That way you never need to add items manually (like you've done here).

Answer (score -1):

`inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);` inflates the `res/menu/main.xml` file, adding any `item` found in that file to the menu. Remove that line or the item from `main.xml` that you don't want to appear in your menu.